# Getting button to align center in Bootstrap card footer

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5.1.3 and trying to get a button to center in the footer of a card.  Here's the code I'm using:

## CSS

```
.btnStandard {
    min-width: 10vw;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div class="card-footer justify-content-center">                    
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success d-flex justify-content-between btnStandard">
      <div class="col-10 text-start">Tell Me</div>
      <div class="col-2 text-center"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-info"></i></div>
   </button>
</div>
```

Nothing I've tried will let me center the button in the card footer.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Display:flex, justify items:center on the footer div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the Bootstrap class `d-flex`.

Change this...

```
<div class="card-footer justify-content-center">                    
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success d-flex justify-content-between btnStandard">
      <div class="col-10 text-start">Tell Me</div>
      <div class="col-2 text-center"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-info"></i></div>
   </button>
</div>
```

...to this.

```
<div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-center">                    
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success d-flex justify-content-between btnStandard">
      <div class="col-10 text-start">Tell Me</div>
      <div class="col-2 text-center"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-info"></i></div>
   </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well:

```
<div class="card-footer mx-auto justify-content-center">                    
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success d-flex justify- 
      content-center btnStandard">
      <div class="col-10 text-center">Tell Me</div>
      <div class="col-2 text-center"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-info"></i> 
      </div>
   </button>
</div>
```